# Apache Spark RDD distinct - strange behaviour

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a `pairRDD` of size 80'000. Only 1.5% of the entries are unique. To filter out the replicated data I call the `distinct` method:

```
val newRDD = oldRDD.distinct
```

However, this only removes the majority of the duplicate data - it leaves between 3-5 duplicates for each unique entry!

I check the remaining entries vs the original entries and they are exactly the same.

```
Sample of the original data:

(1,(0.0500937328554143, 0.9000767961093774))
(1,(0.0500937328554143, 0.9000767961093774))
(1,(0.0500937328554143, 0.9000767961093774))

Sample of the distinct data:

(1,(0.0500937328554143, 0.9000767961093774))
(1,(0.0500937328554143, 0.9000767961093774))
(1,(0.0500937328554143, 0.9000767961093774))
```

Is there something that I am missing about how `distinct` works?

Answer (score 1):

These numbers compare equal after being converted to strings, but based on how `distinct` treats them they must not compare equal before the conversion. Instead of printing them, check the result of comparison (`==`).

Comment: At least that's my guess. If they do compare equal, there has to be a subtler explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Daniel. I wonder why this is occurring though and why out of 135 entries it determines 3 to be different from the rest and also, from each other (I did `distinct` on them again and they all remained in the RDD). It's also strange because I put 1 entry into the map and just copy it. I then take them out and they have changed. Odd behaviour.

Comment: What did you find? Do they compare equal with `==`? It really is a strange behavior. Even through all serialization and transmission I would not expect equal numbers to become non-equal.